# URL Rewrite IIS and search engine

Tags: iis, search-engine, url-rewrite-module

I've configured my IIS (asp.net site) to use URL Rewrite.
In particular this is my rule (dynamic one): whatever url in format number/string will be redirected to a special aspx page.

SSo whatever url starts with mysite/id/Name is redirected to showprof.aspx?id=id&title=Name. This works perfectly.

My question is about search engines. I don't have any "fixed" page that contains links like mysite/id/Name that the spider can scan, so I'm trying to figure it out how search engines could index my dynamic pages. Should I create a sitemap.xml? if yes in wich way? or should I create a "hidden" page that contains every link to all my dynamic contents like mysite/id1/Name1 mysite/id2/Name2 and so on?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

A starting point is definitely a Sitemap.xml, You could try for example the IIS SEO Toolkit and see if it is able to index any of your pages: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/search-engine-optimization-toolkit

It also has functionality to generate a sitemap.xml, although I'm guessing in your case you probably have some dynamic content, so a better approach would be to have a "handler" that generates it dynamically on demand (maybe cache it for performance reasons).

I would also recommend to have some pages that actually are accessible through normal links, for example maybe have in your home page of the site a link to a "site map" page (not sitemap.xml), where there you render a set of links that you want to index (at least the ones that are most important to you), and that will make them easy to discover.